# Copying sql table contents from one table to another - conditionally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables
`positions`  - which contains one field called '`tripname`'
`trips` - which contains a field called '`name`'

I use a csv file from which data is imported in to these two tables and now I need to do some further updating and am a little stuck.

The '`positions`' table is updated by the addition of as many rows as are contained in the csv files. One field is called '`tripname`' (which contains a value) another is called '`FK_Trips_ID`' (which is added as NULL).

The  '`trips`' table is updated with only one row (if it did not already exist)which contains a field called 'name' and another called 'ID'.

Here's where I am stuck. I need to:

```
Insert into the 'positions.FK_Trips_ID' field the value of the 'trips.ID'
where the 'trips.name' is equal to the 'positions.tripname
- BUT only if 'positions.FK_Trips_ID' is NULL
```

I cannot find a similar example of this type of insertion and wondered if some kind soul could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is to `UPDATE` column `FK_Trips_ID` from table `positions` based on the matching record on the `trips` table.

You can join both table to have only one request on the database,

```
UPDATE  positions a
        INNER JOIN trips b
            ON a.tripname = b.name
SET     a.FK_Trips_ID = b.ID
WHERE   a.FK_Trips_ID IS NULL
```

For faster performance of the `UPDATE` statement, the columns must be index to avoid from performing *Full Table Scan* which causes slow when doing it on large databases.

```
ALTER TABLE positions ADD INDEX (tripname);
ALTER TABLE trips ADD INDEX (name);
```

Comment: Thanks JW - your response was much appreciated. I see the logic and difference between 'Insert' and 'Update'. One further question if I may. In the 'trips' table there is a further field 'FK_Users_ID. If I wanted to update this in the 'positions' table at the same time (same condition) - how would that affect your statement.

Comment: It's OK JW - after a few tries I figured it out. Thanks again for your help.